# Is it possible to create ipv4-enabled Docker Machine on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Given fresh Windows 10 pro installed and latest 1.13.1 (10072) "Docker for Windows", if I create a new machine via:

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv node1
```

The machine will have only ipv6 address attached to it. Simple commands like `docker ssh node1` will work, but if I try something advanced like "docker swarm" it will fail:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                                     SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
node1   -        hyperv   Running   tcp://[fe80::215:5dff:fe0f:ae10]:2376           v1.13.1
```

Is it any way to create and IPv4 docker machine, or it's not intended to be used on Windows boxes?

Comment: When I created a new switch with the specific name "Primary Virtual Switch" only then i get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (when i selected the Wireless adapter)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23685967)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You have to use external network switch.

To create external network switch open hyper-v manager and then open virtual switch manager.

[Related docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/)

Finally create node with this command (**Primary Virtual Switch** is the name of the external virtual switch):

> docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary
>   Virtual Switch" node1

Comment: Be aware that an external switch using a WiFi adapter may cause stability issues. IE: Blue Screen problems.

Comment: How does this answer his question?  He wants to use IPv4 over 6, all this does is sets up the VM to use an external switch, the OS will still use IPv6.  I only point this out because I'm interested in the same.

Comment: When I use virtual switch, using command docker-machine ls, the url displays in ip4 format. And so docker swarm join works seamlessly.